# Proof for $\gcd$ operation, with out using technique of showing counter-example.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let, denote the $\gcd$ finding operation by $G$. Need proofs for two below statements, with out showing a counter-example case.
1. Proof to show that $G$ does not obey the Cancellation Law. In other words,
given three positive integers $a, b$ and $c$, s.t. that $c G a = c G b$, but $a \ne b$.
2. Proof to show that $G$ is not distributive over $+$ operation, i.e. given three
positive integers $a, b$ and $c,$ s.t. :
$c G (a + b) \ne (c G a) + (c G b)$

Comment: How exactly does one prove such things without showing a counterexample? For any predicate $\phi$ showing $\lnot (\forall x:\phi(x))$ is equivalent to $\exists x: \lnot \phi(x)$, so any proof will produce a counterexample in some way. (Of course the proof may be nonconstructive, but I don't quite see how that should work here.)

Comment: @MatheinBoulomenos You have given logic for showing a counter-example as a must, but still expressed hope for a non-constructive proof.

Comment: Consider $cGa$ for $a=1, 2,3,...$. If the cancellation property holds then the values it takes are all different. But the values it takes are divisors of $c$. In particular less than $c$. Therefore, by the pigeonhole principle two must be equal.

Comment: If (2) holds, then $cG1=1$ and by induction $cG(n+1)=cGn+cG1=cGn+1$ it follows that $cGn=n$ for all $n$. Since $cGn=nGc$ it follows that $n=c$ for all $c,n$, a contradiction. Therefore, for some $n$ the equation $cG(n+1)=cGn+cG1$ fails. I don't know which $n$.

Comment: @sunwarm Thanks for proofs of both statements. I am new to non-constructive proofs. The first proof is not clear to me, as to how it shows that the Cancellation Law is not followed. Your proof by contradiction, using the pigeon-hole principle is not clear to me. As per my knowledge, the principle takes multiple values into a set of slots $\lt$ than number of values; and as you assume multiple values, so $\ge 1$ value must be in the same slot (or the same divisor). But, is it not the reverse, i.e. need prove $a\ne b$, but proving that at least one set of roots is the same. Sorry, if wrong.

Comment: @jitender If two values $a,b$ (in particular, because they are two they are different $a\neq b$) return the same value, then $cGa=cGb$ and that is your example.